# Postgres to php Array

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a table with values :

```
CREATE TABLE grade
(id int, name varchar(2), no int);

INSERT INTO grade
(id, name, no)
VALUES
(1, 'A', 7),
(2, 'B', 6),
(3, 'C', 10),
(4, 'D', 12),
(5, 'E', 15),
(6, 'F', 21),
(8, 'B', 16),
(7, 'F', 18),
(9, 'F', 25);
```

I need output in arrays to use.. i.e. :

```
[
  ['range','A','B','F'],
  ['0.00 - 4.41', 1, 1, 0],
  ['4.41 - 8.24', 0 , 1, 1]
  ...
  ...
  ['others', 0, 0, 1]
]
```

This is what I am tring ([Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/54104/2)) :

```
    select range, array_agg(name) as name, array_agg(count) as count
    from (
        select case
          when no between 0.00 and 4.41 then '0.00 - 4.41'
            when no between 4.41 and 8.24 then '4.41 - 8.24'
            when no between 8.24 and 14.77 then '8.24 - 14.77' 
            when no between 14.77 and 19.35 then '14.77 - 19.35' 
            when no between 19.35 and 23.00 then '19.35 - 23.00'
        else 'Others' end as range, name,  count (*) as count
        from grade
        WHERE name IN ('A','B','F') 
        group by range, name
        order by name
    ) t
    group by range
```

Is it possible to get desired output from db query only ? or I have use php to iterate through?

Comment: Where do you get those histogram bucket sizes from? They're all uneven. I was going to suggest using the `width_bucket` function, but it's only for regular histograms.

Comment: I am using elester Slider where user can create ranges and based on this ranges i want to create stacked bar graph. I am using google visualizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to archive result ([Updated Fidddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/54104/11)):

```
    select range, sum(a) as a_name, 
                  sum(b) as b_name, 
                  sum(f) as f_name, 
                  sum(count) as total
    from (
        select case
          when no between 0.00 and 4.41 then '0.00 - 4.41'
            when no between 4.41 and 8.24 then '4.41 - 8.24'
            when no between 8.24 and 14.77 then '8.24 - 14.77' 
            when no between 14.77 and 19.35 then '14.77 - 19.35' 
            when no between 19.35 and 23.00 then '19.35 - 23.00'
        else 'Others' end as range, 
                count(name = 'A' OR NULL) as A,
                count(name = 'B' OR NULL) as B,
                count(name = 'F' OR NULL) as F,  
                count (*) as count
        from grade
        WHERE name IN ('A','B','F') 
        group by range, name
        order by name
    ) t
    group by range
```